# SCROLLVIEW minimum zoom size

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

guys.i'm new to iphone.i run the zoomingpdfview demo,everthing is fine,except that i don't want the pdf is zooming out smaller than the screen's size,or even very small..
i've tried many ways,but still can't.
so,how can i achieve that goal?thanks in advance.,any advice will be gratefull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a property on a UIScrollView called minimumZoomScale. However, this isn't measured in pixels, it's measured as a factor of the size of the view.

You will need to calculate the min zoom yourself i.e.

```
// for a pdf width 230 and screen width 360 your min zoom would be 2.0
//     a pdf width 720 and screen width 360 your min zoom would be 0.5

// So, to set the zoom for a scroll view
[myScrollView minimumZoomScale:screenWidth / pdfWidth];
```

However, you might have to calculate this for each visible page - pdfs can have pages of different size :)